# Picking Up Repositories With Structuremap

Tags: interface, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am not sure how to use StructureMap to scan for all repositories in a particular namespace. Most repositories take the form:

```
namespace CPOP.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class PatientRepository : LinqRepository<Patient>, IPatientRepository
    {
    }
}

namespace CPOP.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class LinqRepository<T> : Repository<T>, ILinqRepository<T>
    {
    }
}

namespace CPOP.Domain.Contracts.Repositories
{
    public interface IPatientRepository : ILinqRepository<Patient>
    {
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
x.Scan(scanner =>
{
    scanner.Assembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ILinqRepository<>));
})
```

But, it only picks up the `LinqRepository` class. What's the best way to pick up the various repositories I'll be dumping in there?

And, as per Joshua's reuest, here's an example of use:

```
namespace CPOP.ApplicationServices
{
    public class PatientTasks : IPatientTasks
    {
        private readonly IPatientRepository _patientRepository;

        public PatientTasks(IPatientRepository patientRepository)
        {
            _patientRepository = patientRepository;
        }

        public Patient GetPatientById(int patientId)
        {
            int userId; // get userId from authentication mechanism

            return _patientRepository.FindOne(new PatientByIdSpecification(patientId));
        }

        public IEnumerable<Patient> GetAll()
        {
            int userId; // get userId from authentication mechanism

            return _patientRepository.FindAll();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of interfaces/base classes going on there. Can you show an example of how you will retrieve a repository? What interface will you be requesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with just one line of code in your configuration.  Assuming you have this:

Entities:
- Customer
- Order

And have a generic repository model like this:

- Repository : IRepository

And have a app services that look like:

```
public AppService(IRepository<Customer> custRepo, IRepository<Order> orderRepo)
```

You would have something like this.  Notice the bit about using the scanner to hook up your custom repositories.

```
public class SmRegistry : Registry
    {
        public SmRegistry()
        {
            For(typeof (IRepository<>))
                .Use(typeof (Repository<>));

            //using this will find any custom repos, like CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>
            //Scan(scanner =>
            //         {
            //             scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            //             scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IRepository<>));

            //         });
        }
    }
```

Assuming your Repositories are defined in some other assembly from your application, you can use Registries to hook it all together.  Check out this post:

http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/24/using-structuremap-to-configure-applications-and-components/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
        Assembly ass = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        Container.Configure(x => x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.Assembly(ass); 
            scan.LookForRegistries();
        }));
```

Then the Registry class:

```
public sealed class MyRegistry : Registry
{
 ...
```

Comment: I was looking for something that would collect them automatically without having to specify each one individually in a registry class, because they'll all have repeated dependent interfaces and classes.